# What is the number of comparisons required to search an element in a sorted linked list in the worst case?

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, search, linked-list

This was a question from a quiz in data structures and algorithms course at my college

> What is the number of comparisons required to search an element in a sorted linked list in the worst case?

These are the options:

> a. ceil (n/2)
>
> b. ceil (log n)
>
> c. n2
>
> d. ceil ((log n) + 1)
>
> e. n

As per the answer key the correct answer is n.

But i thought this way, in a sorted linked list, the search needn't move through all the elements. It can jump to the second node from the current (like `curr->next->next` and keep a previous pointer like `prev = curr->next`) and see if that node has key less than the key to be searched for,

If the key to be searched is larger than the current node's key, we repeat this.

Else, we compare the search key with `prev->key` and if they are equal then the element is found or it is not present in the linked list

This method would cost around (n/2) comparisons (+ 1 in case of comparison with previous)... So the answer should be ceil(n/2) right? Am I correct?

EDIT: This is the c version of the algorithm that i mentioned above (The head of the linked list and the key to be searched for are the arguments. skey is the key to be searched for)

```
void search (struct node * head, int skey)
{
    struct node * curr = head,*prev = NULL;
    
    
    while(1)
    {
        if(curr==NULL)
        {
            if(prev!=NULL)
            {
                if(prev->key== skey)
                {
                    printf("FOUND");
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("NOT FOUND");
                    break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                printf("NOT FOUND");
                break;
            }
        }
        if(curr->key==skey)
        {
            printf("FOUND");
            break;
        }
        else if (curr->key < skey)
        {
            if(curr->next!=NULL)
            {
                prev=curr->next;
                curr=curr->next->next;
                
            }
            else
            {
                printf("NOT FOUND");
                break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(prev!=NULL)
            {
                if(prev->key== skey)
                {
                    printf("FOUND");
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("NOT FOUND");
                    break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                printf("NOT FOUND");
                break;
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you know `cur->next->next` exists?

Comment: Technically you would still be right "*de jure*" even if you decided to first transfer the linked list into an array and then do a binary search of that array, and thus reach the conclusion that you only need O(log(n)) *comparisons* to find the key. At some point, I think you'll have to buy into the notion that "this was not what the question asked for".

Comment: The question says *worst* case. What if the element to be found is the last one on the list? Having a sorted list doesn't improve the worst case as you may still need to look at every element.  (I don't understand how your proposal helps anyway).

Comment: This seems odd.  @Dolda2000 is correct that a binary search can be performed because it is already sorted... I cannot imagine why it would be n.

Comment: @Jedediyah: You can't perform a binary search on the linked list directly, as you cannot index it. As I wrote, you'd have to first transfer it into an array. (Doing that wouldn't require any comparisons, however.)

Comment: @Mat that we don't know what $n$ is seems weird and subtle.  Even in that case though, you still don't need to make the comparisons as you travel through the list.  In fact, your first step could be to traverse the list  to count how many nodes there are, without making any comparisons.

Comment: @Jedediyah: how do you move to the next node without a compare (next != null)?

Comment: @Dolda2000 Inspired by your lateral thinking. You actually can do a binary search without an array. Just *traverse* to the middle of the list and *compare* that one value. Then repeat with the half of the list where the target value is known to lie based on the sorting order. Technically no comparisons of the value are done during traversal :-)

Comment: @kaylum: lol, true enough. :)

Comment: @Dolda2000 you don't have to index it directly though, you can traverse it to count the nodes, then just keep track of which node you are at.  Then you can move around without making comparisons until you are at your target node.  It's not pretty, but...

Comment: Probably just an unclear question.  The instructor seems to be referring to a singly-linked list.  The example you refer to is a doubly-linked list (both forward and backward).

Comment: @Mat of course that's true, but it seems the question must mean a comparison of the content of the node.  If next!=null counts as a comparison, then the answer would be larger than $n$.

Comment: Even if the data structure is a sorted linked list, since the number of comparison is the only thing that matters, then the [Binary search algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) would perform `log(n)` comparisons at most. The linked list will be read many times, but who cares if the `compare()` function is the bottleneck ?

Comment: I have included the c code for the algorithm

Comment: @Jedediyah: but as Francis says, if traversing the list is free, then you can do a binary search (either by brute-force repeated traversals, or building an index array on the side). I doubt that's what the instructor had in mind.

Comment: @Mat Yes, as I said in my first post I believe it can be done with a binary search. But again, if you are counting counting the null pointer check as a "comparison" then the answer key is still wrong!

Comment: I do not agree with the answer `n`.  Because need to make two comparisons for each node in the linked list.  1) check if at end of list 2) check if desired entry.

Comment: I count some 9 comparisons in the posted code for each entry in the linked list. (Note: not all comparisons will be performed for every entry in the linked list.

Answer (score 0):

here is a way to step through the linked list with only 2 comparisons per node.

```
while( curr = head; curr != NULL && curr->skey != skey; curr = curr->next);
```

worst case is the `skey` is not in the linked list

Answer (score 0):

It depends too much on how the search is implemented.

Examples:

- A very badly implemented search could check/compare the same entry 20 times before moving to the next entry.
- You could implement a binary search and reduce the worst case number of comparisons (while increasing the number of times you do `current = current->next;` or `current = current->previous;` and making performance worse).
- You could keep track of the "middle entry"; and "almost halve" the worst case number of comparisons.
- You could have an additional array that keeps track of the best place to begin searching (e.g. where the first character of what you're searching for is used as an index into this additional array), and reduce the number of comparisons that way. This includes building the array immediately before searching (as you can build the array without comparisons).
- If the "thing you compare" is small enough (e.g. you're searching for an entry that is a number between 1 and 10), you could convert the linked list into an array and then use an array lookup; and have zero comparisons.

For the most obvious approach (linear search), and only for the most obvious approach, the worst case is that you check all entries and don't find what you're looking for; which is "one comparison per entry" or `N comparisons`.